# Why JSON returns double rows for each row within resultSet

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have the following php code:

```
 echo(json_encode(array('msg'=>'7','result'=>$list)));
```

it returns the following json with ajax:

```
 msg    7
 result […]
        0   {…}
        0   2
        1   Family, Release
        2   test 2 v/s test 3
        3   this is the test for judgment file 2
        4   null
        5   2019-10-10 10:10 PM
        6   1
        7   null
        8   1
        sno 2
        keywords    Family, Release
        case_title  test 2 v/s test 3
        law this is the test for judgment file 2
        judgment_file   null
        added_on    2019-10-10 10:10 PM
        added_by    1
        user_ip null
        is_confirmed    1
        1   {…}
        0   3
        1   Family
        2   Test 3 V/S Test 4
        3   this is tthird record
        4   null
        5   2019-10-10 10:10 PM
        6   1
        7   null
        8   1
        sno 3
        keywords    Family
        case_title  Test 3 V/S Test 4
        law this is tthird record
        judgment_file   null
        added_on    2019-10-10 10:10 PM
        added_by    1
        user_ip null
        is_confirmed    1
```

Problem 1: it returns single row result twice i.e. with 0,1,...8 while with table fields name i.e. sno = 2 keywords = xxx

I need to get single result for each row.

Problem 2: how to get all the fields from json with JavaScript / jQuery?

Comment: is $list already a json? Also, can you format output a bit more. Use `console.log("%j", jsonObj);`  or `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` to print a formatted data on console.

Answer (score 0):

The `$list` itself contains the duplicates and that's what the PHP returns. You must eliminate the duplicates from the `$list` array/object/array of objects in php.

See this working example:

index.php

```html
<button class="button">Get JSON response</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.button').on('click', function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log('Request failed: ' + textStatus);
        });
    });
</script>
```

ajax.php

```php
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $list = new stdClass();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $list->{'name' . $i} = 'Value ' . $i;
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo(json_encode(array('msg' => '7', 'result' => $list)));
}
?>
```

Result:

[image]